# Identify which Flow.js / ng-flow input (flow-btn) was used to upload a file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flow-js, ng-flow

I have multiple `flow-btn` elements on my page. There is a list of items that the user can upload single files directly in to (individually) *or* they can choose to upload multiple files which will automatically populate the list. Everything is inside a `flow-init`.

A bit like this pseudo-code example:

```
<div flow-init>
    <div flow-btn>Upload multiple images to fill the list</div>
    <h3>The list</h3>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div flow-btn flow-single-file>Upload an image for this item</div>
            <img flow-img="item.flowFile">
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

I need to identify which `flow-btn` was used within the list so that I can display the uploaded image thumbnail at the correct point. Basically I think I want access to the `item` from a flow event.

**Note:** The list loop data is defined by other data, so I can't just loop through `$flow.files` to create my list.

How can I do this?

Should I create a new `flow-init` instance for each loop item? Overkill?

**Edit:** Alternatively, perhaps I can open the multiple `flow-btn` from my controller programmatically rather than having a `flow-btn` for each item?? In which case I could stash the current item in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit. 08.2015**
I have checked this once again under firefox and input element appears to be hidden not inside event.srcElement, but in event.originalTarget. I have updated code and plnkr.

---

Well, as you probably know ng-flow provides events. To those events you can pass your functions and inject them with $event object, which has reference to specific button you have clicked. In your case you could listen for *flow-files-submitted* and based on *$event.srcElement* do appropriate actions like this:

HTML

```
<div flow-init flow-files-submitted='handleUpload($files, $event, $flow)'>
     <div flow-btn>Upload multiple images to fill the list</div>
     <h3>The list</h3>
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div flow-btn flow-single-file>Upload an image for this item</div>
            <img flow-img="item.photo" ng-if='item.photo'>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.handleUpload =  function($files, $event, $flow) {
 if(($event.srcElement !== undefined)&&($event.srcElement !== null))
  var input = angular.element($event.srcElement)
 else
  var input = angular.element($event.originalTarget)
 if (input.scope().item) {
  if(input.scope().item.photo) {
    input.scope().item.photo.cancel();
  }
  input.scope().item.photo = $files[0];
 } else {
   for(var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
     $scope.items.push({photo: $files[i]});
   }
 }
};
```

[Check out this Plunker for solution to your problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cky0GIOhQMvRpc50GFdb?p=preview)

Comment: Simple! Thank you :-)